# Google API Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs error "500 Internal error encountered" when trying to create a new "send mail as" account

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I'm updating a PHP application to create new "send mail as" accounts in Gmail (using the Google Service Gmail). I'm able to connect to the account and view alias information from my code so the connection is not the issue. Here is my code

```
  $scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic'
);


$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject('mymainemail@email.com');
$client->setScopes($scopes);  




try {
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);


        $smtpadd = new Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs(array('displayName' => 'display name','sendAsEmail' => 'myalias@email.com','treatAsAlias' => false, 'isPrimary' => 'true', 'isDefault' => 'false', 'smtpMsa' => array(
            'host' => 'smtp.host',
            'port' => 587,
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'mypassword'
        )));

        $results = $gmail->users_settings_sendAs->create('mymainemail@email.com',$smtpadd);

} catch (exception $e) {
        print "Error" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The only time I get a 500 internal error is when I try to add a new "send mail as" account with smtp MSA information. Also this code was working before and recently stop and gave me the 500 internal error.
Here is the error code

```
    Google\Service\Exception: { 
    "error": 
        { 
        "code": 500, 
        "message": "Internal error encountered.", 
        "errors": [ 
            { 
            "message": "Internal error encountered.", 
            "domain": "global", "reason": "backendError" 
        } ], 
        "status": "INTERNAL" 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Your code is a little off for using service accounts with Gmail api.   I think I can help create you a working sample however have you configured [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) to your google workspace account?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send emails with a service account your workspace admin must have configured domain wide [delegation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) to the user on your service account who you wish you send emails on behalf of.

This code should show you how to authorize your application.  It will just list all the messages from your delegated user.

```
scopes = array(
    'Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL'
);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Gmail delegation sample");
$client->setAuthConfig($GOOGLE_AUTH);
$client->setScopes($scopes);
$client->setSubject("user@YourDomain.com");


$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$messages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me');
print_r($messages);
```

If that works then you should consult [users.settings.sendAs#SendAs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs#SendAs) to check the property body for the users_settings_sendAs->create method.

```
$alias = new Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs();
$alias ->sendAsEmail('Alias@yourdomain.com');
$service->users_settings_sendAs->create($this->email, $this->email, $alias);
```

Comment: I have configured domain wide delegation to the user. Both users_settings_sendAs->patch and users_settings_sendAs->get methods work but not users_settings_sendAs->create. Any other suggestion would be appreciated.